# Cannot call web.py application : wsgifunc() failed

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi, web.py

I'm trying to start a `web.py` application on my apache server.
But I received an wsgi error when I try to call any REST service. 
Below my code :

```
urls = (
  '/publication/(.*)', 'PublicationStats',
  '/author/(.*)', 'AuthorStats',
  '/department/(.*)', 'DepartmentStats'
)
application = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
  #web.config.debug = True
  application.run()
```

When I tried to call my REST api like `/author/Smith, John`, my Apache server generate a strange error about wsgi :

```
[Thu Oct 27 15:54:28.614753 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 2979] [client 130.104.xxx.xxx:62194] AH01215: Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://test.dial.uclouvain.be/swagger/
[Thu Oct 27 15:54:28.614841 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 2979] [client 130.104.xxx.xxx:62194] AH01215:   File "/var/www/html/api/dilbert/api.py", line 377, in <module>, referer: http://localhost/swagger/
[Thu Oct 27 15:54:28.614856 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 2979] [client 130.104.xxx.xxx:62194] AH01215:     application.run(), referer: http://localhost/swagger/
[Thu Oct 27 15:54:28.614877 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 2979] [client 130.104.xxx.xxx:62194] AH01215: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'run', referer: http://localhost/swagger/
[Thu Oct 27 15:54:28.636844 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 2979] [client 130.104.xxx.xxx:62194] End of script output before headers: api.py, referer: http://localhost/swagger/
```

If i use only "`web.application(urls, globals())`" it works. But I need to use wsgifunc because i need to access to [`web.ctx.env` variable](http://webpy.org/cookbook/ctx).

`mod_wsgi` is well installed on Apache. It seems works fine... I hope.
Thanks for your help

Renaud

Comment: To me this sounds like the appropriate handler is not being used for your script. In your `.htaccess` file, do you have `SetHandler wsgi-script` for this script?

Answer (score 0):

Base on @sytech suggestion, I update my apache configuration like this :

```
<IfModule wsgi_module>
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  WSGIScriptAlias /api/dilbert /var/www/html/api/dilbert/api.py/
  WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/api/dilbert

  <Directory /var/www/html/api/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    <Files *.py>
      SetHandler wsgi-script
      Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
    </Files>
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Possibly will not matter, although could confuse your application routing, but  you would not normally have a trailing slash on the last argument to ``WSGIScriptAlias``. The ``SetHandler wsgi-script`` directive and ``Options`` directives in that context should not be needed. More likely issue is that your main Apache configuration has ``.py`` mapped to ``cgi-script``. Better to rename ``api.py`` to ``api.wsgi`` and change ``WSGIScriptAlias`` to match. It is stupid that some distros ship with ``.py`` mapped to ``cgi-script``.